# Using Recursive Function to determine how many classrooms that we need

Tags: algorithm, vba, optimization, recursion, nested-loops

I've a problem in VBA.

In db there is a **classrooms** table like

```
id              limit
--------        ---------
103             35
107             42
109             50
201             45
203             54
204             80
...             ...
..              ..
.               .
```

And also **exams** like below

```
exam_id         participants
--------        ------------
1010            105
1011            320
1012            45
1014            283 
...             ...
..              ..
.               .
```

We need to determine **minimum** how many classrooms we need for each exam. Some exams need only one classroom but some needs more than ten classrooms. So I've to cross check each classrooms capacity to choose the minimum number of classrooms without wasting the large classrooms for little groups.

I'm taking exams one by one and try to find a suitable classroom with a for loop

```
'all exams
for a=1 to LastExam

 'with all classrooms
 for b=1 to LastClassRoom

  'if it's the first classroom we're checked
  if tempClass = "" then tempClass = b

  'if this classroom capacity is enough for participants
  if examList(a,1) < classRoomList(b,1) then

   'declare it that we found
   findFlag = 1

   'check is it also better than the temp classroom. If it's then
   'mark it as the new temp classroom
   if classRoomList(b,1) < classRoomList(tempClass,1) then
    tempClass = b
   end if
  end if

 next
next

'if we haven't found an enough capacity for it try two nested loops
if findFlag = "" then
 for a1=1 to lastExam-1
  for a2=a1 to lastExam
   ...
    ..
     .

'if two classrooms are not enough try three nested loop
if findFlag = "" then
 for a1=1 to lastExam-2
  for a2=a1 to lastExam-1
   for a3=a2 to lastExam
    ...
     ..
      .


still not found? try four nested loops
...
..
.
five nested loops
...
..
.
till 16 nested loops
```

Nested **FOR loops** solution is not suitable because there are 16 classrooms and probably the number will increase soon.

I've tried to create a recursive function but I couldn't. I've to admit that it's beyond my skill. I'm open to all advices. Thank you.

Comment: You should've posted the code whatever you've tried

Comment: so what is connection between 2 tables?

Comment: Ok, I'm working on it.

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion: There is no direct connection between two tables it's not the question. I'm taking them one by one and checking all the possibilities to find the most suitable classroom.

Comment: @RohanK: I hope it's better to understand now. Sorry for insufficient information.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a recursive solution where you can do it by sorting one array and and running one for loop??? I think this may help ->

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, k;
    vector< int >hallroom;
    cout<<"How many examHalls ?? :  ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Input ExamHall Capacities : ";
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int idx;
        cin>>idx;
        hallroom.push_back(idx);
    }
    sort(hallroom.begin(), hallroom.end());
    cout<<"How many examinees ?? :  ";
    cin>>k;
    for(int i=hallroom.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        k-=hallroom[i];
        if(k<=0)
        {
            cout<<hallroom.size()-i<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems you missed that part "without wasting the large classrooms for little groups"

Comment: Yeah, i admit that i missed that point and i apology for that. so, what's the first priority? i should minimize the number of rooms? then i should think about not wasting seats ?

Like, using 4 rooms and wasting 10 seats is better than using 5 rooms and wasting 5 seats - am i right ??

Comment: Yes, you're right. First priority is classroom count then seats come.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Probably it can be solved by dynamic programming using bitmask. return a pair of minimized rooms and wasted seats.